# How to make the camera follow the character without dragging the background along with it in screen space camera render mode in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D platfomer and I am using screen space-camera render mode in canvas. Now the background fits inside the screen in every aspect ratio perfectly. But when I make the camera follow the character, the background also comes with it, making the character look like it is not moving.

Code for player movement:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;

    [SerializeField]
    private float movementSpeed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        HandleMovement(horizontal);
    }

    private void HandleMovement(float horizontal)
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2 (horizontal * movementSpeed, myRigidbody.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

Here is the camera follow code:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform target; 
    Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    public float smoothTime = 0.15f;

    public bool YMaxEnabled = false;
    public float YMaxValue = 0;
    public bool YMinEnabled = false;
    public float YMinValue = 0;

    public bool XMaxEnabled = false;
    public float XMaxValue = 0;
    public bool XMinEnabled = false;
    public float XMinValue = 0;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        Vector3 targetPos = target.position;

        //vertical
        if (YMinEnabled && YMaxEnabled)
        {
            targetPos.y = Mathf.Clamp (target.position.y, YMinValue, YMaxValue);
        } 
        else if (YMinEnabled) 
        {
            targetPos.y = Mathf.Clamp (target.position.y, YMinValue, target.position.y);
        }
        else if (YMaxEnabled) 
        {
            targetPos.y = Mathf.Clamp (target.position.y, target.position.y, YMaxValue);
        }

        //horizontal
        if (XMinEnabled && XMaxEnabled)
        {
            targetPos.x = Mathf.Clamp (target.position.x, XMinValue, XMaxValue);
        }
            else if (YMinEnabled)
        {
            targetPos.x = Mathf.Clamp (target.position.x, XMinValue, target.position.x);
        }
            else if (YMaxEnabled)
        {
            targetPos.x = Mathf.Clamp (target.position.x, target.position.x, XMaxValue);
        }


        targetPos.z = transform.position.z;

        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp (transform.position, targetPos, ref velocity, smoothTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have now so that others can help correct it? We don't have the context of what you're doing at the moment.

Comment: @Khalos Its not about the code. Its about the technique. Please don't downvote the question. Anyway I have edited the question. Please see the edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use screen space camera, then the Canvas will move with the camera. I would suggest using Sprite Renderer instead of Canvas panel for level background. If you need to scale the Sprite according to screen, do it from the code. Also, for scrolling the background, you can follow this tutorial:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/2d-scrolling-backgrounds

Comment: Is there any other way? I tried changing the canvas render mode to screen space- overlay. And when I did that, my character got hidden behind the background. I tried changing the z-axis value, but nothing happened.

Comment: If, screen space overlay is selected, it will render above all other graphical objects. In that case, you'll need to put the character also in canvas as a UI object, which is not a good idea. That's why I told to make the background as Sprite renderer rather than Canvas object.

Comment: But when I do that, my background gets stretched/squished to fit screens with different aspect ratio.

Comment: You need to handle that from script to maintain your background sprites scale according to screen size. Have a look at this link:
https://kylewbanks.com/blog/create-fullscreen-background-image-in-unity2d-with-spriterenderer

Comment: But if I opt that method, some part of the image wont be shown on the screen. I need the image to fit fully inside the screen. Height of the image should be equal to the height of the screen. And the width should also scale with the same percentage. However for some aspect ratios, there will be some space uncovered width wise. But that is ok for me. I will anchor the image to the left of the screen and attach the next frame to the right of this image(1st frame).

Comment: Do you know how to scale the image so that the height of the image will be equal to the height of the screen and the width of the image will be scaled with the same percentage?

Comment: Please go through the tutorial link and try to understand it. In the tutorial, the sprite is scaled according to the orientation it is in. But for your case, you need to scale it according to the height. So, if you use this line, it should work: scale *= cameraSize.y / spriteSize.y;

Comment: Please mark it as a right answer, if it solves the problem.